# What is the total number of wrong answers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In a certain test, $a_i$ students gave wrong answers to at least $i$ questions, where $i=1,2,...,k$.

No student gave more than $k$ wrong answers. What is the total number of wrong answers?

$\text{My attempt}$

$a_{i+1}$ students gave wrong answers to at least $i+1$ questions and $a_i$ students gave wrong answers to at least $a_i$ questions. Therefore, $a_{i+1}-a_i$ is the number of students who gave wrong answers to exactly $i+1$ questions. Then, I would calculate the same for all possible $i$. How would I go afterwards?

Comment: You've done the tricky part - now just group the students according to their exact number of wrong answers and add up all of their wrong-answer counts.

Comment: Actually it looks like you've gotten something backwards. Note that $a_i\ge a_{i+1}$ and review your analysis a little more carefully.

Comment: Please provide the **exact wording of the question**.

Comment: @user2661923 I think we can interpret the phrase "$a_i$ students gave ..." as "the number of students who gave ... is $a_i$". That is, the $a_i$ stands for a number as in "two students gave ...".

Comment: @Karl I suspect that you can make an educated guess as to the problem composer's intent.  Such a guess would imply a reasonable algebra problem to solve.  However, it is unclear to me whether there is only one unique such guess of the problem composer's intent.

Comment: Is it that much of a leap to assume a symbol stands for a number where a number makes sense grammatically? I agree that a different wording would be clearer, though.

Comment: In any case, sadly, making educated guesses about the problem writer's intent is a huge part of being successful in school math.

Comment: @Karl In my opinion, in a situation such as this, it is generally the responsibility of the original poster to determine/guess the problem composer's intent, before posting the question.  Often, the original poster didn't present the problem as it was originally given.